# subtracting the minimum value in a file with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, radix

I need some help with shell script.

I have the following text file (open_calculator[1]):

> value:0,0236679
>   value:0,0272904
>   value:0,0282416
>   value:0,0295671
>   value:0,0318641
>   value:0,032451
>   value:0,0333313
>   value:0,0360229
>   value:0,0364378

And I need to get the minimum value of this file and subtract it of the other values of the same text file. So my output should be:

> value:0,0000000
>   value:0,0036225
>   value:0,0045737
>        .
>        .
>        .
>   value:0,0127699

In order to achieve this, I wrote this script:

```
file="open_calculator[1]"

min= cut -f2 -d ":" $file | sort -n | head -1
number=$(grep -o '[0-9],[0-9]*' $file)
resul=$((10#$number - 10#$min))

sed -i 's/value:$number/valor:$resul/' $file
```

---

but when I run this code, I get this message error:

```
line 6:10#0,0236679: value too great for base (error token is "0236679")
```

Someone could help me with this script? Sorry for my bad English, it's my first time writing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do these values denote floating point/decimal numbers ?

Comment: Yes, these values are decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code as following:

```
tr ',' '.' <open_calculator[1] > file  #Converting each , to . to make these numbers decimal

min=`cut -f2 -d ":" file | sort -n | head -1` 

awk -F":" -v m=$min '{print $1":"($2-m) } ' file | tr "." ","
```

Output:

```
value:0
value:0,0036225
value:0,0045737
value:0,0058992
value:0,0081962
value:0,0087831
value:0,0096634
value:0,012355
value:0,0127699
```

**Solution 2** : One liner using **awk** and **tr** only

```
tr "," "." <open_calculator[1] | awk -F":" 'NR==1{a[NR]=min=$2} {a[NR]=$2; a[NR]<min?min=a[NR]:min; } END{for(i=1;i<NR;i++){print "value:"a[i]-min}}' | tr "." ","
```

Here we are finding min in awk itself and subtracting from second column. The result from awk is piped to tr to translate "." to "," to match your desired output.

Comment: The desired output is colon separated and uses a comma as the decimal point, though.

Comment: Thank you, batMan.
The second solution works fine, but how can I save the output in the file?

Comment: I did it. I just have to use:
>> "open_calculator[1]"

Comment: okay, great. But also mention such requirements in your original question too from next time.

Answer (score 0):

bash doesn't handle floating point arithmetics.

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {
             s/,/./;
             ($n) = /([0-9.]+)/;
             $min = $n unless defined $min && $min < $n;
         }
         open ARGV, $ARGV;
         while (<>) {
             s/,/./;
             s/([0-9.]+)/$1 - $min/e;
             s/\./,/;
             print;
         }' -- filename
```

The first loop finds the minimum, then `open` reopens the file again and the second loop subtracts the minimum. The substitutions are needed as Perl uses decimal dot, not comma.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know perl, but now I will starting study.